# IE: How can I keep my webpage up if I lose internet connection until it comes back?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection, internet-explorer-10

I'm hoping there is a setting or method to disallowing the web page redirect when I lose connection.  For instance, I'll be typing up a document online and if I lose internet connection from my wireless connection then the webpage with the document gets lost and I get the no connection page from IE.  Is there anyway to make it stay on the previous page that way when the connection comes back I can continue the report and not lose the information?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Docs this should not happen. This issues sounds more like an issue of the site you are using. I recommend using other browsers or using a different site to type up documents. For instance: Chrome has offline features for Google Docs (and other applications in the Google Drive suite) that will allow you to work offline and automatically backup every time you reconnect.